# facebook v2.0 ios sdk get other user's basic info struggle

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Welp, since facebook sdk v2.0 came out, I'm having a huge problem completing basic tasks that I was easily able to do so before.

I would expect the graph call `/v2.0/<some_other_user_id>` (of a different user, not the one logged in) to return that user's basic information. I read the upgrade log, and the whole new thing with app specific facebook id's, so I create test users, logged them in, and then tried `FBRequestWithGraphPath` with these test user's new app specific fb id and still doesn't work...any ideas/help to how this process is suppose to work? I am currently try this way:

1. FB Login to my app with my real facebook account
2. FB Login test users to my app
3. Attempt to get the other users basic information with a FBRequest:

-

```
[FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"271837716321713 parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

Step 3 isn't successful and returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```